# Reverse RegEx MatchCollection Items?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, vb.net, reverse

There is a way to reverse the items of a RegEx.MatchCollection?

For example if a MatchCollection contains those matches:

```
a1
a2
a3
```

Then I want to reverse the collection items so the item index would be this else:

```
a3
a2
a1
```

...Preserving their match index and other match information as lenght, groups, etc.

Comment: does it need to be another `MatchCollection` or can you just grab the `Matches` and reverse them, e.g,. `var reversed = matches.Cast<Match>().Reverse();`

Comment: @sa_ddam213 thanks for comment, is not sufficient with a Reverse Ienumerable I still lost, I think does not matter the type of collection while I still can retrieve the item information that I need, but I'm not sure, you are the expert, thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not quite a `MatchCollection`, but an `IEnumerable<Match>`

```
 myMatchCollection.Cast<Match>().Reverse()
```

Good enough, probably.

Comment: thankyou but I'm not much experienced with IEnumerables, I need to cast the reverseiterator to other type? how I can do it then to retrieve the matches info?, tried to make a MatchCollection using LINQ with the IEnumerable but the 'Match' and 'Matchcollection' does not have the 'New' constructor so something like this can't work:  matches = matches.Cast(Of Match)().Reverse().Select(Function(m) New Match(m))

Comment: ouch, thanks for your time, I've done it as an Array and all works good:         Dim var = matches.Cast(Of Match)().Reverse().ToArray
        MsgBox(var.First.Groups(0).Value)

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET version:

```
 Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
 Dim matches() As Match = Regex.Matches("ABCDA", "A").Cast(Of Match).Reverse().ToArray()

 MsgBox(matches.First.Index) ' Result: 4
```